# What is the weight that is used to balance an aircraft called?

Tags: weight-and-balance, cg

I remember I was reading about balancing an airplane a few days ago, and i came across a type of weight that is added to balance the airplane. But, I do not remember what it was called.

Also could someone tell me the approved location of these weights on a Boeing 747-400?

Comment: Related: Water [Why would a glider have water ballast?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/606/why-would-a-glider-have-water-ballast-if-it-is-trying-to-stay-aloft-without-an/) and fuel [Is passenger weight distribution important on a commercial flight?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/is-passenger-weight-distribution-important-on-a-commercial-flight) Also for [flight testing](http://cdn-www.airliners.net/photos/airliners/6/4/9/0958946.jpg?v=v40) and [conspiracy theories](http://www.boeingimages.com/Docs/BOE/Media/TR3_WATERMARKED/d/4/4/2/BI223325.jpg).

Answer (score 15):

747s in everyday operation typically use fuel for ballast when needed. Ballast fuel is considered to be part of the zero fuel weight and you are not allowed to burn it, although obviously if you were about to run out of fuel, it's available.

Ballast fuel is carried in either the center tank or distributed evenly in the four main wing tanks. Individual carriers have different ideas insofar as their preference for either center tank or wing tank ballast fuel. Also, after the TWA 800 explosion back in the late 1990s, there were as I remember special rules for a time on carrying ballast fuel in the center tank.

Should you wish to explore the effects of ballast fuel on the CG of a 747-400, go to [747.terryliittschwager.com](http://747.terryliittschwager.com) and select the first aircraft N402YY. When the aircraft comes up, you'll notice that the BALLAST FUEL radio buttons at top center have the Center Tank selected. If you put 100000 lbs of fuel in and then 1000 lbs of ballast, you'll see the zero fuel weight CG change from 30.6% MAC to 30.8% MAC.

Ballast fuel is more often necessary for 747s that were originally passenger airplanes and then converted to freighters than otherwise. The problem is that the heavy structure added for the large cargo door aft of the wing brings the basic operating weight CG farther aft then before the cargo conversion. 747s originally manufactured as freighters do not have this problem as they have additional structure for the nose cargo door in addition to the side cargo door structure.

Answer (score 12):

I am pretty sure you are thinking of [ballast](http://www.flight-mechanic.com/the-use-of-ballast/). These kinds of weights are used aircraft and in many other types of vehicles as well, particularly in ships, to maintain proper balance.

Comment: Get it? But seriously thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually called as ballast. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_gravity_of_an_aircraft):

> Ballast is removable or permanently installed weight in an aircraft used to bring the center of gravity into the allowable range.

Comment: Could you tell me where they are placed on a Boeing 747-400?

Comment: @DevanshRathi It depends on requirements- for example, for example, [in this article](http://jalopnik.com/plane-porn-the-very-first-boeing-747-inside-out-1563321442), they are placed near the nose. During flight testing, they are shifted around to determine the effects of shifting cg on the aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

It is called **ballast** - part of the inherited ship terminology- or **counterweight**. Placed where it produces the necessary torque for balance. Usually in the nose or tail. I don't have data specific to 747-400 but here's a [somewhat related article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/593649.stm).